# How can I strip the "/blog/" prefix from specific WordPress posts

Tags: wordpress

The main website is not run on the WordPress CMS, but the blog is. The blog is installed at https://www.vaperempire.com.au/blog/, which causes all blog posts to receive a permalink like vaperempire.com/blog/post-title. How can I strip the /blog/ part of the permalink from specific posts?

Comment: Even if you  strip the blog part somehow, the URL will no longer be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this because your primary CMS exists on the root folder of your domain while the wordpress CMS exists in the subfolder. I'm not sure what primary CMS you are using but I doubt it would be possible to install wordpress to your root folder alongside of your other CMS due to conflicting files/libraries.

You would have to create the post on your primary cms if you want a page without the /blog/ subdirectory. However, you could then redirect to it from a blank post on wordpress (e.g. domain.com/blog/desired-post-url -> domain.com/desired-post-url) in order to allow people to access it from your wordpress site. You could even iframe your primary CMS page from your wordpress post if you wanted to go that route, but it might not be a very good viewing experience.

Comment: I assume you are correct in this regard and that the content will have to be published on the primary CMS in order to strip "/blog/" from the URL. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You would need the rewrite module of Apache: mod_rewrite in your htaccess code to make this happen:

Maybe something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ $1
```

Here is the official documentation of [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

You can check your .htaccess file on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Would this strip /blog/ for ALL blog articles? I only want to strip the /blog/ prefix from specific articles. Is there a way I might go about this?